# how to get the actual object Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i'm using for the first time Struts + Java. I have the following:

```
package Logica;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class Partido extends ActionForm {

    private String local;
    private String visitante;
    private String campeonato;
    private String hora;
    private String fecha;

    private Resultado actual;



    public void setLocal(String local){
        this.local = local;
    }

    public void setVisitante(String visitante){
        this.visitante = visitante;
    }

    public void setCampeonato(String campeonato){
        this.campeonato = campeonato;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora){
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha){
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }


    public Resultado getResultado(){

        if(actual == null){
            actual = new Resultado(0, 0);
        }


        return actual;
    }

    public String getLocal(){
        return local;
    }

    public String getVisitante(){
        return local;
    }
    public String getCampeonato(){
        return local;
    }
    public String getHora(){
        return local;
    }
    public String getFecha(){
        return local;
    }
}
```

This is the JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Proyecto Web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h2>Agregar Partido</h2>
            <s:form action="nuevoPartido" method="post">
                <s:textfield name="local" size="10" label="Local" />
                <s:textfield name="visitante" size="10" label="Visitante" />
                <s:textfield name="nombreCampeonato" size="10" label="Campeonato" />
                <s:textfield name="hora" size="10" label="Hora" />
                <s:textfield name="fecha" size="10" label="fecha" />
                <s:submit value="Guardar" />
            </s:form>
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I want to get that object Partido that I create with the form and insert it in a List. The problem is that I don't know how to get the object Partido in another Java Class.

Comment: I don't think people will be able to help you when your code is in Spanish.

Comment: What version of Struts?

Comment: Struts2 last version

Comment: @FunctionR it's Spanglish, the keywords are in English :)

Comment: @Mario : there is no ActionForm in Struts2. You are creating a Chimera

Answer (score 0):

You need not extend any ActionForm or ActionSupport Classes in Struts2 when you use simple programs.

I think you have the getters and setters and action method in the same action class.
What you can do is, 
1) Create a separate bean class for the form elements(Use separate Class for action and beans)
2) In your action class create an object for the bean and generate getters and setters for the object
3) if you are using this approach then you have to rename the form values prefixed with bean class name

Lets say your bean class name is **PartidoBean**. In your form, you have to access the form names with **partidoBean**.

**FROM**

```
 <s:textfield name="local" size="10" label="Local" />
 <s:textfield name="visitante" size="10" label="Visitante" />
 ...
```

**TO**

```
<s:textfield name="partidoBean.local" size="10" label="Local" />
<s:textfield name="partidoBean.visitante" size="10" label="Visitante" />
...
```

You now have the values of the StrutsForm in your bean object present in Action method of the ActionClass. You can send this beanObject to another class by creating an object for the required Class.

This is one approach for transporting formValues to different classes. 
I guess this is your requirement!!